# two nvidia cards setup requires new driver?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Can anyone tell me if I need to re-install the nvidia driver if I add a second card?

Reason for this question is, the nvidia user guide says (really for windows users) I have to completely get ride of whatever nvidia driver i have currently,  and reinstall with the latest version on the DVD.

I'm trying to avoid doing that. Last time I installed nvidia driver on ubuntu, it was a nightmare. Everything broke and took me weeks to restore my system.

Here is my setup : Ubuntu 14.04. Current card is GTX 660 Ti, new card is GTX 980 Ti.

Answer (score 0):

According to NVIDIA's documentation at http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/92826/en-us you don't need to install a new driver, as the Nvidia Linux-Drivers support a wide variety of models.

As per today, the latest stable release of the NVIDIA propetiary drivers (352.55) support both cards:

> GeForce 900 Series: GeForce GTX TITAN X, GeForce GTX 980 Ti, GeForce
>   GTX 980, GeForce GTX 970, GeForce GTX 960, GeForce GTX 950

and

> GeForce 600 Series: GeForce GTX 690, GeForce GTX 680, GeForce GTX 670,
>   GeForce GTX 660 Ti, GeForce GTX 660, GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST, GeForce
>   GTX 650 Ti, GeForce GTX 650, GeForce GTX 645, GeForce GT 645, GeForce
>   GT 640, GeForce GT 630, GeForce GT 620, GeForce GT 610, GeForce 605

Nevertheless, I'd recommend backing up your system before you attempt swapping the graphic card.

Regards

Comment: Just installed the second card in the third PCIe slot. Reboot. Then  ls -l /dev | grep nvidia*. I only see 'nvidia0' and 'nvidiactrl', where the second is the controller. No sign of my GTX 980.

Comment: What do you see in "Additional Drivers"?

Comment: i see a list of 7 nvidia drivers with names "Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.96 from nvidia-346 (proprietary, tested)", some say "legacy". But they are all greyed out. The only active item is "Continue using a manually installed driver"

Comment: Turns out the driver version is 340.29. Maybe too old for GTX980?

Comment: Afraid so, your driver only includes until the 800M series... Nevertheless, you should be seing the latest version in that screen. If you don't, open a terminal window and do a "sudo apt-get update" followed by a "sudo apt-get upgrade" and try again. Do that with the old card installed. Update, select the newest driver, and switch to the new card.

Comment: I've been avoiding apt-get upgrade for fear that other packages also get upgraded and become incompatible with my other stuff. Is there anyway to just apt-get upgrade a specific item? Sorry real newbie linux Q....

Comment: Just do an "apt-get update" (without upgrading) then and see if you see the new drivers

Comment: Noop. same 7. greyed out.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install nvidia-352", reboot, check again